# Cannot import datasets into doccano

Tags: doccano

I have tried different format to upload in doccano like text line, excel. But It was always spinning, even <1mb file also not uploading. What to do?[It was spinning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeZeO.png)

I am expecting the solution for this problem please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the spinning problem. we should run a command "

> doccano task

" in a another terminal. so that doccano knows to store temporarily the uploaded json or text file.